# Just the MySQL username please. Not the host

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm already aware of `USER()`.  How do I just get the username - i.e the stuff before @

```
+------------------+
| USER()           |
+------------------+
| billy@localhost |
+------------------+
```

I want simple `billy`. This will be used in a TRIGGER.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1);
```

See: [Information Functions: USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user)

Answer (score 2):

from help:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1);
```